# R SQL templating with glue_sql, ability to dynamically drop where clause

Tags: r, dplyr, dbi, r-glue

**TLDR**
I would like to be able to template SQL queries and run them in R. The glue package and DBI work great, but I can't figure out a way to template statements. In other words, is there a way to do something like this (borrowing from [jinja](https://www.webforefront.com/django/usebuiltinjinjastatements.html)):

```
SELECT * FROM mtcars 
{% if length( {make} ) > 0 %} 
WHERE make IN( {make*}
{% end %}
```

**Additional Detail**
DBI and glue work great for a single use case, but often I want to reuse the same general SQL code with a few different variations of `WHERE` clauses and things like that. Often I want the `WHERE` to be "off". in some of the use cases and not in others (e.g. for `WHERE IN()` it defaults to all values, for `WHERE x >= y` it doesn't apply the conditional at all, etc.).

The only solution I can find is to evaluate inputs in R as [discussed here](https://github%20https://github.com/tidyverse/glue/issues/132), and then pass a default vector or the input. This approach works in some use cases and not at all in others. I think it makes it harder to generalize and has a performance hit in my most common use case - when I want a query with a parameter that passes values to a `WHERE IN()` clause, but defaults to all values. If the table is evolving (i.e. all values changes over time) then I need to first run a query to get all values, then input them if the user doesn't provide values. That can be expensive on larger tables and prohibitive if it's in a user experience (shiny).

```
library(DBI)
library(glue)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts =  F)

# Setup local DB #### 
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
mtcars_df <- tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars, var = "make")
str(mtcars_df)
#> 'data.frame':    32 obs. of  12 variables:
#>  $ make: chr  "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
#>  $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#>  $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#>  $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
#>  $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#>  $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#>  $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#>  $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#>  $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
#>  $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars_df)

# Example query ####
sql <- glue::glue_sql("SELECT * FROM mtcars WHERE make IN( {make*} )", make = c("Fiat X1-9", "Datsun 710"), .con = con)
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, sql) 
#>         make  mpg cyl disp hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1 Datsun 710 22.8   4  108 93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 2  Fiat X1-9 27.3   4   79 66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1

# Templating #### 
sql <- "SELECT * FROM mtcars WHERE make IN( {make*} )"
sql_template <- tempfile(fileext = ".sql")
readr::write_file(sql, sql_template)
read_sql <- function(file, ..., .con, .envir = parent.frame()){
  sql <- readr::read_file(file)
  sql <- glue::glue_sql(sql, ..., .con = .con, .envir = .envir)
}

# SQL files can be templated and called from R
sql <- read_sql(sql_template, make = c("Fiat X1-9", "Datsun 710"), .con = con)
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, sql) 
#>         make  mpg cyl disp hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1 Datsun 710 22.8   4  108 93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 2  Fiat X1-9 27.3   4   79 66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1

# All {values} must be provided, errors out
sql <- read_sql(sql_template, .con = con)
#> Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir): object 'make' not found

# Doesn't return anything
sql <- read_sql(sql_template, make = DBI::SQL(""), .con = con)
print(sql)
#> <SQL> SELECT * FROM mtcars WHERE make IN(  )
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, sql) 
#>  [1] make mpg  cyl  disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

# Can't make the entire where clause a parameter either without doing a lot of escapes and basically defeating the purppose of glue
sql <- glue::glue_sql("SELECT * FROM mtcars {makes}",  makes = "WHERE make IN('Fiat X1-9', 'Datsun 710')", .con = con)
print(sql)
#> <SQL> SELECT * FROM mtcars 'WHERE make IN(''Fiat X1-9'', ''Datsun 710'')'
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, sql)
#>                   make  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1            Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2        Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3           Datsun 710 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 4       Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 5    Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> 6              Valiant 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> 7           Duster 360 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> 8            Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> 9             Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> 10            Merc 280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> 11           Merc 280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> 12          Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#> 13          Merc 450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#> 14         Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#> 15  Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#> 16 Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#> 17   Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#> 18            Fiat 128 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> 19         Honda Civic 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> 20      Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> 21       Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> 22    Dodge Challenger 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#> 23         AMC Javelin 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#> 24          Camaro Z28 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#> 25    Pontiac Firebird 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#> 26           Fiat X1-9 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> 27       Porsche 914-2 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> 28        Lotus Europa 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> 29      Ford Pantera L 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#> 30        Ferrari Dino 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#> 31       Maserati Bora 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#> 32          Volvo 142E 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2

# Get all values first
all_makes <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT DISTINCT make FROM mtcars") %>% dplyr::pull(make)
sql <- read_sql(sql_template, make = all_makes, .con = con)
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, sql) 
#>                   make  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1            Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2        Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3           Datsun 710 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 4       Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 5    Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> 6              Valiant 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> 7           Duster 360 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> 8            Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> 9             Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> 10            Merc 280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> 11           Merc 280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> 12          Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#> 13          Merc 450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#> 14         Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#> 15  Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#> 16 Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#> 17   Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#> 18            Fiat 128 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> 19         Honda Civic 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> 20      Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> 21       Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> 22    Dodge Challenger 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#> 23         AMC Javelin 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#> 24          Camaro Z28 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#> 25    Pontiac Firebird 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#> 26           Fiat X1-9 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> 27       Porsche 914-2 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> 28        Lotus Europa 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> 29      Ford Pantera L 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#> 30        Ferrari Dino 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#> 31       Maserati Bora 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#> 32          Volvo 142E 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2

# Templating with a conditional#### 
sql <- "SELECT * FROM mtcars WHERE cyl >= {cyl} "
sql_template <- tempfile(fileext = ".sql")
readr::write_file(sql, sql_template)
read_sql <- function(file, ..., .con, .envir = parent.frame()){
  sql <- readr::read_file(file)
  sql <- glue::glue_sql(sql, ..., .con = .con, .envir = .envir)
}

# No way to use the all values approach since it's a one sided conditional 
sql <- read_sql(sql_template, cyl = 8, .con = con)
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, sql) 
#>                   make  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1    Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> 2           Duster 360 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> 3           Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#> 4           Merc 450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#> 5          Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#> 6   Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#> 7  Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#> 8    Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#> 9     Dodge Challenger 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#> 10         AMC Javelin 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#> 11          Camaro Z28 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#> 12    Pontiac Firebird 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#> 13      Ford Pantera L 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#> 14       Maserati Bora 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

Comment: It would be easier to just substitute in the entire where clause.

Answer (score 3):

You can use multiple arguments to `glue::glue_sql`:

```r
# con <- dbConnect(...)
make <- c()
glue::glue_sql(
  "select * from mtcars",
  if (length(make)) " where make in ({make*})" else "",
  .con = con)
# <SQL> select * from mtcars

make <- c("Fiat X1-9", "Datsun 710")
glue::glue_sql(                                          # unchanged
  "select * from mtcars",
  if (length(make)) " where make in ({make*})" else "",
  .con = con)
# <SQL> select * from mtcars where make in ('Fiat X1-9', 'Datsun 710')
```

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, that's a clever idea! It definitely addresses my examples in the question, but a lot of my use cases are significantly more complex SQL. Many of them have multiple subqueries so it makes it more difficult to take this approach. Might need to create a better example to get my point across...

Comment: Also from a workflow perspective I'm really trying to keep all the SQL code in a SQL file to decouple the SQL & R development as much as possible, if that makes any sense.

Comment: It's all I could come up with on short notice ;-). Since `glue` doesn't support much in the way of `{%if%}`-like macros like other templating languages do, I suspect you may be in a hard place with regards to a perfect solution. You could always short-circuit the SQL in a way ... `glue::glue_sql("select * from mtcars where ({length(make)}=0 or make in ({make*}))", .con = con)`. That gets tiresome, but if you're trying to insulate other users from the queries, they'll never see it.

Comment: Totally get it and really appreciate the feedback, it's helpful! The {length(make)} is also very clever, but I don't think it will work at all. If I don't give the param it errors, `object 'make' not found`, and if I try to give nothing with `DBI::SQL("")` it evaluates to 1 = 0 which was surprising but makes sense...

Comment: While I'm intrigued by where (I believe) you want to go with this, it might be getting too complicated for simple SO questions; I certainly don't have the time to invest in this right now, unfortunately. I wish you luck!

Comment: No problem thanks @r2evans. The glue repo asks people to post here rather than to github, but my initial desire was to post there as a feature request since I was relatively certain it wasn't possible today...

Comment: I suspect that asking for a full macro addition like `{%if (..)%} ... {%elseif (..)%} ... {%else%} ... {%endif%}` is either outside of their perceived scope, or something they already have planned for version XYZ. Frankly, writing just a wrapper to support those three things by themselves is quite trivial, but the prospects of nesting and other corner-cases make it complicated rather quickly.

Comment: Yea I'm guessing that's outside scope as well because I'm sure they're familiar with that functionality, just wanted to float it in case because it keeps creating friction for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using [jinjar](https://davidchall.github.io/jinjar/) v0.2.0:

```r
query <- "SELECT * FROM mtcars 
{% if length(make) > 0 -%} 
WHERE make IN ({{ quote_sql(make) }})
{%- endif %}"

jinjar::render(query, make = c()) |> writeLines()
#> SELECT * FROM mtcars

jinjar::render(query, make = c("Fiat X1-9", "Datsun 710")) |> writeLines()
#> SELECT * FROM mtcars 
#> WHERE make IN ('Fiat X1-9', 'Datsun 710')
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>